# print full path of file use by symbolic link with in same dir

Tags: bash, shell, symlink

Hi I'm writing a script that will scan dir for symbolic link there are some output that the file is with in dir, so it will look below.

```
/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/precomp/public/SQLDA.H -> sqlda.h
```

I need to print full path, expected result below:

```
/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/precomp/public/SQLDA.H -> /opt/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/precomp/public/sqlda.h
```

any option in ls or readlink or other way I can write in the script?

here is the script I use to search for fix link

```
find $i -type l -ls
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
readlink -f *
```

It will look at all files in the actual directory. For the symbolic links it will read and print the full path of the file the link points to. For other types of entries (directory, normal file) it will print the file name with full path.

Comment: Hi quantummind - can you add a bit of an explanation of what this does, and why it will solve the questioner's problem? It will make your answer better, both for the original questioner and for other readers looking for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `gnu find` then you can use `-printf` option:

```
find "$i" -type l -printf "$PWD/%h/%f -> $PWD/%h/%l\n"
```

Comment: hi this work but seem got extra entry "/root/scripts/"
 /root/scripts//opt/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/precomp/public/SQLDA.H ->  /root/scripts//opt/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/precomp/public/sqlda.h

here is my script
    for i in $(mount -v | grep vg01 | awk {'print $3}');do
        find $i -type l -printf "$PWD/%h/%f -> $PWD/%h/%l\n"
    done

expected output 
    /opt/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/precomp/public/SQLDA.H -> /opt/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/precomp/public/sqlda.h

thanks in advance

Comment: ok try this command: `find "$i" -type l -printf "%h/%f -> %h/%l\n"`

Comment: it work but it messy the one that has full path already.

/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/bin/lbuilder -> /opt/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/bin//prime/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/nls/lbuilder/lbuilder
/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/precomp/public/SQLDA.H -> /opt/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/precomp/public/sqlda.h

here is the the that has full path already it added 
/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/bin/lbuilder -> /opt/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/bin//prime/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/nls/lbuilder/lbuilder

Comment: ok, try this: **`while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do printf "%s -> %s\n" "$PWD/$file" $(realpath "$file"); done < <(find "$i" -type l -print0)`**

Comment: I did a different approach but thanks I have use the 
find "$a" -type l -printf "%h/%f -> %h/%l\n"